# Indexing documents in Elastic Search using Refresh.True - Performance hit and how can it be improved?

Tags: c#, performance, elasticsearch

I have an AWS Elastic Search server. 
Using mapping template and an index strategy.

```
{
  "index_patterns": "users*",
  "order": 6,
  "version": 6,
  "aliases": {
    "users": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "keyword" },
        "emailAddress": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index strategy is `{index_patterns}-{yyyy}-{MM}-{order}-{version}`

Using NEST SDK to index document in a background application consuming SQS messages with the below method.

```
public async Task<Result> IndexAsync(
            T document, 
            string indexName = null, 
            string typeName = null, 
            Refresh? refresh = null, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {   
            var response = await Client.IndexAsync(
                                                document, 
                                                i => i.Index(indexName ?? DocumentMappings.IndexStrategy)
                                                        .Type(typeName ?? DocumentMappings.TypeName)
                                                        .Id(document.Id)
                                                        .Refresh(refresh), 
                                                cancellationToken);

            var errorMessage = response.LogResponseIfError(_logger);

            return errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? Result.Ok() : Result.Fail(errorMessage);
        }
```

This is a base method and is called like this.

```
var result = await _usersRepository.IndexAsync(userDocument, refresh: Refresh.True, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Here I am using `Refresh.True` because this is a user signup and I want the document to be available ASAP but noticed a performance hit, it takes a while for example to index 50,000 users in a load test.

`Refresh.True` refreshes all shards for this index, now I do this for each request of 50,000 calls and it seems like I get the hit.
Any input how can I improve this?